# How can I transfer all of my contacts from Google to Live.com

Tags: windows-live, google-contacts

I have linked my Google account to Live.com, and now my Google contacts are visible in Live.com.  However, I would rather copy all of the contact data into Live.com, so that I can shut down my Google account.

Is there an intelligent way to do this, or do I really have to export from Google in a CSV formatted file, and then import the file into Live.com?

Comment: Live.com - do you mean Outlook.com?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not Windows Phone related. It is better suited on SuperUser.

Comment: Yes, I mean Outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are asking for this because you'd like to sync your Windows Phone contacts only with Outlook.com.

In Outlook.com choose contacts from the pop-up list (the arrow next to outlook logo on the left) and there choose import from .CSV file (you must have exported first your contacts in contacts.google.com to a .csv file).

After the import is completed you should check all your info is now on outlook.com, in case you have linked it with Google you can now revoke access to Google and just keep using Outlook.com

Comment: The reason I'd like to avoid CSV format import, is that it is an error-prone process, with fields likely to be incorrectly mapped.  I do a lot of "extract-transform-load" type work at my day job, and I know that CSV is hard to work with, especially when the data is as complex as a set of personal contacts.

Comment: If you don't like the CSV option, then there's a Google Contacts option as well which will connect to your Gmail/Google account and copy over the contacts.

Comment: Neil, are you sure?  I think you are referring to the "Manage Accounts" feature, which is what I am trying to avoid, because it does not actually copy the data into Outlook.com.  There is no "copy from Google Contacts" option in the "Importing contacts" dialog.  I see only: "Step 1. To bring your contacts into Outlook, first go to your other email service and export them to a file. Then come back here. Step 2. Select the service you're importing contacts from: () Microsoft Outlook (using CSV), () Another Outlook.com or Hotmail account. Step 3. Choose the file to import."  Is yours different?